# How can i print Duplicate qweb report in odoo?

Tags: python, report, odoo, qweb, odoo-14

I have created a report that is working fine
now I have created a button in my form's header name "Print Duplicate" that will print the same report.

However, when I click on '**print duplicate**' button , I want to print "Duplicate Report " on top of my report:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiu67.png)

Object called on button click:

```
def print_duplicate_report(self):
returnself.env.ref('token_management.report_token_receipt').report_action(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to print a report twice on same pdf while clicking "print duplicate button". If my understanding is right, then here is a solution,

```
    <template id="report_deliveryslip">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
<t t-set="list_of_copy" t-value="['(DUPLICATE1)','(DUPLICATE)']"/>
<t t-foreach="list_of_copy" t-as="copy_name">
            <t t-call="stock.report_delivery_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
</t>
        </t>
    </template>
```