# How to duplicate Quotation/Order report and customize the duplication?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-15

I would like to create a similar Quotation/Order report, without adding any line to the files code (I agree on changing/adding new lines on the database)

The Quotation/Order is perfect for sending it to the clients during the negotiation, but after selling the goods, I would like to print a Label with less data than Quotation/Order report.
Basically the new report will have the following info:

- Quotation Number
- Client Name, VAT, Address, Logo (logo is already working on my Quotation/Order report)

This label will be fixed on the pack in order to make the transport easier.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Odoo 15 version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69373776/how-can-i-print-duplicate-qweb-report-in-odoo

Answer (score 0):

You could create another label and make it available on the drop down from the action or print menu located in the center.

Name it something unique.

could do this through studio if you have no real experience with the xml or module development.

You could even limit the print to be visible only when the order is in a certain state .